# Interpolate value which has 2 known series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, interpolation

I have a dataframe like:

```
Beta  | Z   |  K
2     | 0   | 1.2
2     | 1   | 1.5
2     | 2   | 1.7
3     | 0   | 1.3
3     | 1   | 1.7
3     | 2   | 1.9
4     | 0   | 1.5
4     | 1   | 2.0
4     | 2   | 2.2
```

I would like to interpolate `K` values at `Beta = [2.2, 3.4]` (for instance). How can I do it such that the interpolation is done separately for each `Z` value?

Comment: What do you mean "if Beta = [2.2, 3.4]"?

Comment: we have Beta = [2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4] ; Z = [0,1,2,0,1,2,01,2] and K =[...] as the table show, suppose value of beta = 2.2 or 3.4. How can I get correspond value of K (should be a list of 3 numbers_which corresponded with Z = [0,1,2].

Comment: Now I understand. Are you still interested in an answer? It will take me a while to write up, so I want to make sure you need it.

Comment: I really need it cause I doing a term_project and the dataset is quite large ^^ I can not deal with it by Excel_sheet THANKS

Comment: Have you managed to interpolate on a reduced dataframe (where Z only has one value), for instance `df[df['Z'] == 0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it in two steps.

**First**, solve the problem for a single value of Z.

```
betas = [2.2, 3.3]            # those are the values you want to interpolate at
df_0 = df[df['Z'] == 0]       # reduce the dataframe
a = df_0[["Beta", "K"]].transpose().as_matrix()  # convert to numpy array
np.interp(betas, a[0], a[1])  # use numpy.interp
```

Output: `array([ 1.22,  1.36])`

**Second**, use `groupby` to apply the above solution to each Z-value independently:

```
# put it all in a function
def f(df):
    a = df[["Beta", "K"]].transpose().as_matrix()
    return np.interp(betas, a[0], a[1])
df.groupby("Z").apply(f)
```

Output:

```
Z
0    [1.22, 1.36]
1    [1.54, 1.79]
2    [1.74, 1.99]
```

Comment: woah! it work! Thanks in advance